# MatLab: estimate number of iterations

Tags: approximation, matlab

I want automatically estimate iterations number in matlab.

Suppose we have `for(int i = 1; i < N; i++)`. It's clear that for-loop prodices `N` iterations. But if we'll take the next loops:

```
for (int h = N/3; h >=1; h = h/3) 
  for (int i = h; i < N; i++)  
    for (int j = i; j >= h; j -= h) 
      doSmth();
```

it isn't clear enough how many times `doSmth()` function will be invoked.

**Question:** Can Iestimate in MatLab number of iterations? How?

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop is executed $\lfloor \log_3 N\rfloor$ times.  For each of these, the inner loop is executed less than $N$ times, so the second loop runs less than $N \log_3 N$ times.  For each of these, the innermost loop is run less than $N$ times, so the total is less than $N^2 \log_3 N$ runs.  Both the second and third are overestimates-some more care can reduce it.  The second does run about $N$ times when $h=1$.  The third runs $N$ times when $h=1, i=N$.   I believe the asymptotic value is correct, but there will be a leading fraction.

Comment: I get the same result. But seems it's wrong. Why? Because the three-loops above - implementation of shellSort algorithm, and it has complexity O(N^(3/2))

Comment: moreover  `N*log(3)N` is a very rough estimate, I'm asking how to calculate the precise number of iterations in MatLab. P.S. How do you type formulas in this forum?

Comment: True, it is a rough estimate.  You can look at each step for refinement.  For a given $N$, you can just let doSmth be m++ and count the runs.  That might show a pattern.  I would look most closely at the inner loop-maybe it runs less than that.  For formulas we use MathJax, putting $\LaTeX$ between dollar signs.  An intro is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)